# Rescue OS with VNC on by default

Tags: linux, headless, rescue-disk

I have a linux box that has been running headless as my home server for a year. I've decided it's time to upgrade the OS and do some other things, so I took it out of the closet, disconnected the data HDD and attempted to turn on.

Unfortunately it didn't boot or at least doesn't want to connect to the network. Before I go looking for a display to diagnose a problem I wanted to ask if there is a rescue Linux distribution, that is configured to boot with VNC enabled I can use to access the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize [system rescue cd](http://www.sysresccd.org/) and add vnc server autostart. If you just want one vnc session, you just need one display. For static network configuration you can just use something like the following

```
rescuecd vncserver=1:MyPaSsWd eth0=192.168.124.10/24 gateway=192.168.124.1/24
```

and you will be able to connect with “vncviewer 192.168.124.10:0“.